# Permission to view my report on report server web portal

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I created my report with an output parameter and deployed it on my report server and it was deployed successfully, and i can have access to it from my machine but when another user want to have access to the report on the report server web portal, it is giving the following errors:

> An error has occurred during report processing. (rsProcessingAborted)
>   Query execution failed for dataset 'DataSet1'. (rsErrorExecutingCommand)
>   For more information about this error navigate to the report server on the local server machine, or enable remote errors

Can anyone help me with solutions

Comment: Where is the `DataSet1` located?

Comment: The Dataset1 is located in an oracle DB which i used sql Linked server to query from  in the form of store procedure with 2 output parameters.

Comment: try using fixed credentials for your datasource connection if possible (I'm assuming you are using the current users credentials at the moment)

Comment: I used Windows Authentication credentials for my datasource connection...

Comment: Here is the problem; if i don't add parameter to the report and deployed it, other user will have access to the report using their Windows Credential but when i add parameter to that same project and deployed it, other user will not be able to access it. I have check the Dataset and Datasource are all working from my end but it keep giving Dataset connection error from other user.